# Gson: Erro de conversão JsonObject para JsonArray (JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Estou tentando converter um item do JSONObject em um ArrayList e pra isso criei essa função a partir de um exemplo que vi aqui no fórum:

```
public static ArrayList<Produto> converte(JSONObject jsonObject){
            ArrayList<ArrayList> array = new ArrayList<>();
            String stringJSON = jsonObject.toString();

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(stringJSON);
            JsonArray jAProdutos = jObject.getAsJsonArray("produtosFavoritos");
            ArrayList<Produto> arrayProdutos = gson.fromJson(jAProdutos,ArrayList.class);

            return arrayProdutos();
}
```

Mas está dando o erro:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be
>   cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

JSON:

```
{"produtosFavoritos":"[]",
"listas":"[]",
"estabelecimentosFavoritos":"[]",
"email":"teste",
"experiencia":0,
"nome":"teste",,
"senha":"teste",
"nivel":1}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar o json que você está parseado?

Comment: Acrescentei na pergunta

Comment: Então, o problema é que o seus arrays estão com aspas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o formato do seu JSON está incorreto. Quando você tem um array, ele não pode estar dentro de `"`. Seu JSON corrigido ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "produtosFavoritos":[],
  "listas":[],
  "estabelecimentosFavoritos":[],
  "email":"teste",
  "experiencia":0,
  "nome":"teste",
  "senha":"teste",
  "nivel":1
}
```

Um outro problema que pode ocasionar erro neste código é o retorno. `arrayProdutos`não é uma função, portanto não deve ter `()`.

Comment: Mas como eu faço para criar o json dessa forma? Quando coloco os produtos favoritos, por exemplo, eu faço jsonUsuario.put("produtosFavoritos", usuario.getProdutosFavoritos()); e já gera assim automaticamente

Comment: Ah deu certo! eu fiz um cast pra JSONArray na hora de adicionar no JSON: jsonUsuario.put("produtosFavoritos", usuario.getProdutosFavoritos());
Muito obrigada!